# Cannot making new controller after upgrade Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-apicontroller

I cannot create a new controller on my ASP.NET MVC API. When I try to create a new controller, Visual Studio 2019 always throws an error (as shown in the screenshot):

[image: Error creating controller]

I used Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 before, and it worked normally. But after upgrade, I have several issues with this IDE like creating controller in my existing project and cannot create a new ASP.NET Core MVC web application.

Hopefully anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That error message means there is no relative templates when you try to add the controller using visual studio wizard.
**Try to install MVC 4 Package.**
This link might be helpful too [Modify Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Hi Mike, Acctually I was installed MVC 4 Package too. check this following image:
![installed mvc 4](https://i.ibb.co/X7hgBt3/installed.png)

Comment: Yes, I was tried running VS as Administrator and still not work

Comment: Try to uninstall Nuget and reinstall it. If it still persist I have no idea then I hope someone else can help out